# How do I become fierce deity early?

Tags: zelda-majoras-mask-3d

Apparently, Majora's Mask 3D has an exclusive glitch that allows you to become fierce deity without having the fierce deity mask through a pretty specific glitch. How can I perform this glitch? Every explanation I can find so far just says "you perform this glitch in this context and you are now fierce deity". What do I need to do specifically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here is a video of it being done](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LELzTIuEZvs).  Description of the video contains the steps to take.

1. Do an [ESS bottle dupe](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A6QsEjaxw0I) over Kafei's Mask or Bremen Mask and then get Hot Spring Water in that bottle (this is BA which means Bottle Adventure).
2. When you exit the area you're in, you come out as Fierce Deity (you can also change by warping with Song of Soaring)
3. Changing Masks lets you switch back to another form since now the game lets you switch masks with FD on. You no longer get stuck as FD outside boss rooms.

*NOTE: Don't do this if you want 100% because the dupe is permanent. Also, it doesn't work if you already have the actual FD mask.*